# Python dictionary lookup returning multiple results?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, initialization, switch-statement

I have a written a simple `class` with an `__init__` emulating a switch/case flow:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print "hello bar"
 
    def haz(self):
        print "hello haz"
 
    def nothing(self):
        print "None"
 
    def __init__(self, choose_me):
        {'foo': self.bar(),
         'can': self.haz()
         }.get(choose_me, self.nothing())
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo('foo')
```

Why is everything being selected? - Here is the output it gives me ([run it with ideone](http://ideone.com/Q0GIJH)):

> hello bar
>
> hello haz
>
> None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot how Python's evaluation strategy worked, was expecting something lazier… rewrote my code so it now works:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print "hello bar"

    def haz(self):
        print "hello haz"

    def nothing(self):
        print "None"

    def __init__(self, choose_me):
        {'foo': self.bar,
         'can': self.haz
         }.get(choose_me, self.nothing)()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo('foo')
```

http://ideone.com/kAH5sk

Answer (score 0):

In your init method, you are calling the functions `bar` and `haz` and put the result in the dictionary:

```
{
'foo': self.bar(),
'can': self.haz()
}
```

You probably wanted to write `self.bar` and `self.haz` without the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the choice to a variable and then run the variable as a function.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print "hello bar"

    def haz(self):
        print "hello haz"

    def nothing(self):
        print "None"

    def __init__(self, choose_me):
        choice = {'foo': self.bar,
         'can': self.haz
        }.get(choose_me, self.nothing)
        choice()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo('foo')
```

Assigned the results of the dictionary lookup to a variable choice then invoking **choice()**
Outputs

```
hello bar
```

Comment: Or you can just add the `()` on the end of the dictionary (like in my answer)…